Token get expired while using Microsoft Graph API
I'm using the Microsoft Graph API for my internal application. First I'm using this url to generate an access token:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/token

Then I'm calling the Graph API:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

To fetch the contact of a user, I'm using this API:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/contacts

But the issue is: my token gets expired. How can I refresh token without end user interaction?

I usually use this function
function GetGraphToken {
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]
        $ClientSecret,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]
        $ClientID,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]
        $TenantID
    
    )
         
    # Construct URI
    $uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
         
    # Construct Body
    $body = @{
        client_id     = $clientId
        scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
        client_secret = $clientSecret
        grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    }
         
    # Get OAuth 2.0 Token
    $tokenRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
         
    # Access Token
    $token = ($tokenRequest.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token
    return $token
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
